# Prevent CalendarApp from creating duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

---EDITED---
I think I found a way to solve this without saving IDs anywhere.

Thanks for your replies. Full code below:

```
// -------------- EDIT CODE BELOW FOR NEW CLIENT ------------

  //EDIT CODE IN BETWEEN THESE LINES ------------------- ( more code to be edited below) //
  var client = "CLIENTNAME";
  var email = "EMAIL";
  var calId = "c_7esq0q0d1n06ao5bc7ueqt7dp8@group.calendar.google.com";
  //EDIT CODE IN BETWEEN THESE LINES ------------------- ( more code to be edited below)

//Common data for all triggers
// getting data from spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssurl = s.getUrl();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Projects');
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); //get last row with data
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numCols);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

// Triggers below  --  Triggers below --  Triggers below --  Triggers below

function AddProjDeadlinesToCalendar() {

//RFQ event creator
//looping through all of the rows
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];

var rfqColumn = row[10];   // ENTER THE COLUMN NUMBER, STARTING FROM 0, FOR THIS DEADLINE
var rfqTitle = row[0] + ' ready for RFQ.'; // ENTER THE TITLE OF THE EVENT
var rfqDescript = row[0] + ' design files should be ready for RFQs by this date.'; // ENTER THE DESCRIPTION OF THE EVENT

var rfqExpireDateDay = new Date(rfqColumn).getDate();    
Logger.log(rfqColumn);
    
//-------------- Add event to Calendar ----------
if (!isNaN(parseFloat(rfqExpireDateDay)) && isFinite(rfqExpireDateDay)){

    // Determines how many events are present in this calendar, from now till the next 365 days, that contains a keyword
        var now = new Date();
        var inAYear = new Date(now.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId).getEvents(now, inAYear,
            {search: rfqTitle});
        Logger.log('Events with same title already present: ' + events.length);

        // If there is more than 0, get event's ID and do not create this event.
        if (events.length > 0){
            for (i=0; i<events.length; i+1){
                var eventIDold = events[i];
                Logger.log('Event ID already present : ' + eventIDold.getId());
      return;
                }
        }else{
        //Creates an all-day event and logs the ID.
            var rfqEvent = CalendarApp
            .getCalendarById(calId)
            .createAllDayEvent(rfqTitle, new Date(rfqColumn),
            {description: rfqDescript});
            Logger.log('Newly created Event ID: ' + rfqEvent.getId());
        }
}         
}
} 

//-------------- Add event to Calendar ---------- ENDS HERE
```

It works, but it stops at the first event that is already present on the calendar (return) and will not check for all other rows in the column's array.

Both break and continue lead to an endless loop. My basic knowledge of coding doesn't let me see the problem. I bet it's in plain sight.

-----END EDIT----

I'm need of help for my script that feature the CalendarApp.

I am already using the script below to create new events with a template for the description and title.

```
---------- Add event to Calendar ----------
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(expireDateDay)) && isFinite(expireDateDay)){
        //Creates an all-day event and logs the ID.
        var event = CalendarApp
          .getCalendarById('calendarIDhere')
          .createAllDayEvent(row[0] + ' ready for RFQ.', new Date(rfqColumn),
          {description: row[0] + ' exampletexthere'});
        Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());

    }
 //-------------- Add event to Calendar ----------
```

The script gets some data from a previously created array (row[0]) and gets the event's date from, again, a previous variable (rfqColumn).

The main script loops through all rows in a specific column (rfqColumn) and creates events for each date it finds in that column. Title and description are gathered from the same row as where the date is found.

I have ready many threads about the CalendarApp and how to prevent duplicates. None of them use this feature as I do.
If possible, *I would like to avoid having a sheet with all the calendar's events IDs.*

Is it possible to:
Every time a new event is created, check if there's already an event with same title and update it if so?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will spend a minute sharing his expertise.

Comment: Please focus your question. Why is your script creating duplicate events?

Comment: You probably need to have some column in your data that keeps track of events that have already been added to your calendar like maybe eventid.  But you havent provided any example of that sort code or have shown us what you data look like

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have edited the main post. Looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Code edit below in case it could help someone.

In my specific case, there could be only one instance with same title, so the for loop can end after first occurrence. (j<1).

```
if (events.length > 0){
            for (j=0; j<1; j++){
                var eventIDold = events[j];
                Logger.log('Event ID already present : ' + eventIDold.getId());
      }
```